# J2ME: Receiving a notification without running the application

Tags: java-me

I wanted to know that is it possible to receive a notification on cell phone without running the application in j2me...
if anybody knows plz reply as soon as possible..

Comment: Hey thanx for reply, actually i want my application to send a notification to the user everyday... so do u have any idea as to how to go about...

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is is possible using the [Push Registry mechanism](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/pushreg/)

you just need a MIDP 2.0 enabled phone.

Comment: Hello, is it possible to get the time when we install the application in j2me

Comment: @Shweta Shah yes it is possible to get the time